# Is this 1L bottle of Blue Label a special edition or a regular one?

Tags: whiskey, alcohol

[image]

There's this bottle of Blue Label and I wanted to know if it's a *limited edition*?

Comment: Are you asking whether the Blue Label is special in itself - or whether the 1 liter version of it is? One liter bottles are (at least in Europe) pretty normal when purchasing Duty Free

Comment: I want to know whether this bottle is special because the color is slightly different. Also, on the box, it doesn't say 'Blended Scotch Whisky', it just says 'Scotch Whisky'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Is this 1L bottle of Blue Label a special edition or a regular one?**

The bottle in your post is a regular Blue Label Johnnie Walker whiskey.

> [**Blue Label**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnnie_Walker): Johnnie Walker's premium blend. Johnnie Walker Blue Label is blended to recreate the character and taste of some of the earliest whisky blends created in the 19th century. It bears no age statement. Bottles are numbered serially and sold in a silk-lined box accompanied by a certificate of authenticity. It is one of the most expensive blended Scotch whiskies on the market, with prices in the range of US$174 - $450. Over 25 Limited Editions have been released to date.

If it were a ***limited edition***, it would be clearly marked on the bottle a such!

The following image bears this out:

[image: Johnnie Walker Blue Label Scotch Whisky Chinese New Year Edition]

[Johnnie Walker Blue Label Scotch Whisky Chinese New Year Edition](https://www.lcbo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/en/lcbo/whisky-whiskey-15020/johnnie-walker-blue-label-scotch-whisky-chinese-new-year-edition-541615#.YR0dSMoTGhB)

Answer (score 5):

It's not a special edition of Johnnie Walker blue label, it's just a Duty Free Edition, thus the 1 litre size.

The missing "Blended" on the label comes from it's production year. It seems to be from the 70s or 80s, and in that time there was no consistent label regulation for blended malt whiskies. The term "Blended (Malt) Whisky" became part of the scotch regulation in the 90s, before that some distilleries used "Pure Malt", "Vatted Malt" or just "Scotch Whisky".

The same for "Single Malt", as well. Glenfiddich started using this term in the 60s. Before, whiskies that would qualify as a Single Malt were called "Unblended All Malt", for example.

I would recommend buying a current bottling of a Johnnie Walker Blue Label and comparing those two. Should be very interesting to see the development.